# Column of text needs "summed" based on assigned value

Tags: microsoft-excel

On one sheet, I have a table with an employee name in column A and their associated rank in column B. On a separate sheet, I have a blank master schedule with all possible shifts in column B and days of the week in row 1. I would like to be able to type the employee's name in the cell associated with the shift they will be working. After filling in the schedule, I would like excel to "add" up the ranks to get a sum total for each day. If there are empty cells, they would be given a value of "0". I made it work using the following formula:

=SUM(COUNTIF(C2:C19,{"A","B","C"})*{1,2,3})

where A, B, and C represent the employees' names and 1, 2, and 3 represent their associated ranks, but admittedly that was before I introduced the possibility of blank cells. The problem there is that I have to freetype it all, and if a rank changes, or an employee changes, I have to edit everything individually. I'm really hoping there's a way to reference my table and I'm just not getting it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please add some example data, it's hard to understand your question now.

Comment: For example, John S is a 2 in the ranking table, Jane D is a 4, etc. (all employees are assigned a value of 1 through 4 - that value is their rank). If I type John and Jane into the same column, that column should always have a sum total of at least 6. If I add other employees to the table, the sum total would increase based on their "rank".

Comment: entering your original formula as an array formula (pressing CTRL + ALT + ENTER instead of just ENTER) replacing `{..}` to ranges, doesn't work? `=SUM(COUNTIF(C2:C19,sheet1!A:A)*sheet1B:B)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create dynamic ranges names for the employee names and the ranks, for example

```
Names   =Sheet1!$A$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))
Ranks   =OFFSET(Names,0,1)
```

[image]

On the other sheet, use the formula

=SUM(COUNTIF(C2:C19,Names)*Ranks)

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

You can now add new names to the employee list...

[image]

... and use that name in the shift roster. The formula will show the correct result.

[image]

Comment: Oh my lanta. This is incredible. As soon as I can get home and NOT try to reply from a work computer, you will get all of the up arrows. Thank you!!!

Comment: You're funny. Let me know if it works or if you need more guidance.

Comment: I just finished putting the formula everywhere I need it, and it works like gangbusters!